# Как выбрать всё между кавычками?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть строка и в ней две кавычки, между которыми может находится все что угодно. Как это всё выбрать? В общем нужно все между кавычками, но не включая их самих.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат во второй группе:

```
/(["'])(.+?)\1/
```